# Сборный iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу сообразить, как все это написать. Как должно работать представить могу, а сделать рабочий код знаний не хватает. Буду рад за код и за наставление.
Необходимо собрать src из input`ов. 
Input '*site.com' radio + input text = src, который запускается.
iframe src должен меняться по клику на submit.

Предпочтителен js/jq

Благодарю

[image: Готовый фронт]

Comment: "iframe src должен меняться..." - меняться с чего на что?

Comment: Более подробно описал...

Comment: чтобы решить задачу разбейте её на маленькие составные части и решайте, тем более вы представляете как это должно работать, данный форум помогает вам решить задачу, но НЕ решает её за вас

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Думаю принцип понятен.

```js
$('#url').on('click', function() {
  let bg = $('input[name="bg"]:checked').val(),
    t = $('input[name="c"]:checked').val(),
    text = $('input[name="text"]').val(),
    theme = `https://via.placeholder.com/150/${bg}/${t}?text=${text}`;
  $('#frame').attr('src', theme);
});
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 160px;
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
}

iframe {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="left">
    Color background:<br>
    <input id="bg1" name="bg" type="radio" value="2DBB1C">
    <label for="bg1">Green</label><br>
    <input id="bg2" name="bg" type="radio" value="F22727">
    <label for="bg2">Red</label><br>
    <input id="bg3" name="bg" type="radio" value="EAF510">
    <label for="bg3">Yellow</label><br>
    <input id="bg4" name="bg" type="radio" value="1067F5" checked>
    <label for="bg4">Blue</label>
    <br><br> Color text:<br>
    <input id="t1" name="c" type="radio" value="FFFFFF" checked>
    <label for="t1">White</label><br>
    <input id="t2" name="c" type="radio" value="000000">
    <label for="t2">Black</label>
    <br><br> Text:
    <br>
    <input name="text" type="text" value="test">
    <br><br>
    <input id="url" type="button" value="Submit">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <iframe id="frame" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/1067F5/FFFFFF?text=test"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Минус без причины - признак дурачины.